# How to remove vertical spacing before and after toc lof & lot in multitoc?

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocloft, multitoc

[image: This is the current output im running]

So far I'm not really sure how to format the toc the packages I use are:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,spanish,utf8,latin1]{report}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{ansiapaper,left=1in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm} 
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

   



\usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{imakeidx}
    \usepackage{tocloft}
    \usepackage{tocbibind} %Includes "Bibliography" in the table of contents
    \usepackage[toc,lof,lot]{multitoc} %Hacer la table of contents list of figures y list of tables en 2 columnas
    \usepackage[toc, acronym, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}   
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{40pt}
    
    \makeatletter
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
    
    \renewenvironment{theindex}
                   {\section*{\indexname}%
                    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                            {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
                    \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
                    \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
                    \columnseprule \z@
                    \columnsep 35\p@
                    \let\item\@idxitem}
                   {}
    \makeatother
    
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip -1.2cm}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\vskip -1.2cm}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=1cm}
\vspace{-1cm}
\tableofcontents
\vspace{-1cm}
\listoftables
\vspace{-1cm}
\listoffigures
\restoregeometry
\newpage
\end{document}
```

However that didn't seem to work, I just want everything as tight as possible because of space constraints in my document.

Comment: Report class formats the toc etc. using \chapter*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take care of the vertical space, before and after the titles of toc, lof and lot, the package `\titlesec` is sufficient.

Note that the chapters will share the same style.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}    

\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{ansiapaper,left=1in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,footskip=.25in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
%%\usepackage{tocloft}% not used

\usepackage{tocbibind} %Includes "Bibliography" in the table of contents
\usepackage[toc,lof,lot]{multitoc} %Hacer la table of contents list of figures y list of tables en 2 columnas
\usepackage[toc, acronym, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{\chaptername\ \thechapter}{30pt}{}   % changed
\titlespacing*{\chapter} % changed needs \titleformat{\chapter}
{0pt} %left
{0pt} % before separation
{0pt}  % after separation

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}

\renewenvironment{theindex}
{\section*{\indexname}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
    {\MakeUppercase\indexname}%
    \thispagestyle{plain}\parindent\z@
    \parskip\z@ \@plus .3\p@\relax
    \columnseprule \z@
    \columnsep 35\p@
    \let\item\@idxitem}
{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}    

    \tableofcontents
    \renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de Tablas}
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
    \newpage    
    
    \chapter{One}
    1.  \kant[1]
    
    \newpage
    
    \chapter{Two}
    2.  \kant[2]
\end{document}
```